# Flex Slider Teaser thumb image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexslider

```
/* Flex Slider Teaser */
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        animationLoop: true, 
        controlNav: "thumbnails",
        start: function(slider) {
            jQuery( '.flexslider' ).removeClass('loading');
        }
    });
});
```

i am using flex slider but in bottom side thoumbnil images is not showing in slider .\
i checked by http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html 
but it is not working , where should i edit in js ?? my code JS code is written above.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show what HTML you are using in the slider? You need a data-thumb attribute in each slide that references to the actual thumbnail images.

For example:

```
<li data-thumb="images/thumb1.jpg">

    <img src="images/slide1.jpg" />

</li>
```

Comment: yes i solved you are right problem is coming from HTML.